# Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Ex 9.5 (a) in Chapter III construct a flat family $X_t$ such that it's cone is not flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

I have some problems to understand a solution I found of following
exercise from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Ex 9.5 in Chapter III, part (a):

> *Very Flat Families.* For any closed subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$,
> we denote by $C(X) \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$
> the projective cone over $X$ (I, Ex. 2.10).
> (a) Give an example to show that if $\{X_t\}$ is a flat family of closed subschemes of
> $\mathbb{P}^n$, then $\{ C(X_t)\}$ need not be a flat family in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$.

A proposed solution of this exercise I found works as follows:

> Consider the flat (?) family $X_t$ defined by $(1:0:0), (0:1:0)$, and $(1:1:t)$
> in $\mathbb{P}^2$.
> These points are only on a line together at $t = 0$.
> For $t \neq 0$, then $I_{X_t} = \langle xz-txy, yz -txy, z^2-t^2xy \rangle$ .
> Let $\{X'_t\}$ be the restriction of $\{X_t\}$ to $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$,
> then the cone $\{ C(X_t')\}$ will still be flat since all fibers
> have same Hilbert polynomial.
> And some calculations show that the flat limit of $\{ C(X_t')\}$ at $0$
> has embedded point at cone, which is not the same as $C(X_0)$.

I have a basic question about first line: I not understand why
the observation that the family $\{X_t\}$ of $X_t \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ defined
as $(1:0:0), (0:1:0)$, and $(1:1:t)$ is flat *not* contradicts to Theorem 9.9
from Hartshorne:

> **Theorem 9.9:** Let $T$ be an integral noetherian scheme. Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_T$ be a
> closed subscheme. For each point $t \in T$, we consider the Hilbert polynomial
> $P_t \in \mathbb{Q}[z]$ of the fibre $X_t$ considered as a closed subscheme of
> $\mathbb{P}^n_{k(t)}$· Then
> $X$ is flat over $T$ if and only if the Hilbert polynomial $P_t$ is independent of $t$.

Doesn't it not contractict to the flatness of family $X_t$ from above?
Indeed this family sits as closed subscheme $X_t \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times\mathbb{A}^1$,
therefore if it is flat by the Theorem all fiberes $X_{t_0}=(1:0:0), (0:1:0)$, and $(1:1:t_0)$ should have
same Hilbert polynomial. On the other hand there is a fact that

> The Hilbert function of three points in $\Bbb P^2$ is
> $$\begin{cases} 0 & n<1 \\ 2 & n=1 \\ 3 & n>1\end{cases}$$ if they're collinear,
> or $$\begin{cases} 0 & n<1 \\ 3 & n\geq 1\end{cases}$$ if they're not collinear.

(see for example [Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert-Funktion#Beispiele) (in german)
By construction of $X_t$ only $X_0$ consists of three collinear point,
every $X_t$ with $t \neq 0$ not. Therefore fibers $X_0$ and $X_t$ should have
have different Hilbert functions. On the other hand this contradicts
to Theorem 9.9.

Could anybody help me to resolve my confusion?

Comment: Note Hilbert polynomial is not the same as Hilbert function.  The Hilbert polynomial is the eventually polynomial part of the Hilbert function, and they are the same (3 for large enough $n$).

Comment: yes I see now, I confused two notations. For Hilbert *function* $HF: \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N}$ and H Polynomial $P_X$ they coinside only asymtotically as you said, thanks!